# Проблема с циклом: перебор всех выбранных значений из checkbox на удаление/ошибка

Tags: sql, post, checkbox, php, mysql

```
<?
    echo "<table class='ram'><td>фио преп<td>должность
        <td>степень<td>контакт<td><form action=' ' method='post'>
        <input type='submit' name='delteacher' 
        value='Удалить выбранное'>";
    $t=("SELECT * FROM `преподаватели`");
$q=mysql_query($t)or die(mysql_error());  
$r = mysql_fetch_array($q);

        do
        {
        echo  "<tr><td>".$r['фио преподавателя']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$r['должность' ]."</td>";
        echo  "<td>".$r['степень']."</td>";
        echo  "<td>".$r['контакт преподавателя']."</td>".
        "<td>";
        ?><input type='checkbox' name='delt[]' 
        value=" <? $r['фио преподавателя'] ?>">
        <?

        }
        while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q));
        echo "</table></form>";
    if(isset($_POST['delteacher']))
{
while($_POST=['delt']);{
foreach($_POST['delt'] as $key=>$value)     
echo $value;

mysql_query("DELETE FROM `преподаватели` WHERE
 `фио преподавателя`='{$r['фио преподавателя']}'");
 echo $r['фио преподавателя'];
                                        }
}
```

> syntax error, unexpected T_WHILE in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\a\t.php

Comment: наверное еще необходима проверка выбрано или не выбраны значения?

Comment: На какой строке выдает ошибку? Так-то ошибки вроде есть, но ни одна не должна приводить к 'unexpected T_WHILE'

  while($_POST=['delt']);

Что именно вы хотите присвоить $_POST?

И если используете цикл, то почему после условия ставите "точку с запятой" - признак конца операции?

Вы в курсе, что если условие выполнится, то будет зацикливание? А если не выполнится, то код в фигурных скобках все равно будет выполнен?

И что вы хотите удалить из базы? Последнюю запись в ней? По коду так...

Comment: Необходимо удалить все строки из таблицы где выбран checkbox 
Если не выбран и  кнопка на уделение с запросом  была нажата то написать сощение что параметр не выбран

Comment: Тогда почему делаете

    DELETE FROM `преподаватели` WHERE `фио преподавателя`='{$r['фио преподавателя']}'

???

Могу дать совет - начните с самого простого - просто циклы, просто работа с БД, просто отображение страницы, просто получение данных со страницы. А потом уже комбинируйте.

Сейчас - у вас знания на нуле. Поэтому ваш код не работает. Поэтому читать его не возможно.

Даже если вам ОЧЕНЬ СРОЧНО надо сделать то, что вы делаете сейчас, все равно - выделите хотя бы день-два на закрепление основ. Потом работа будет идти быстрее.

Comment: @нуб(больше слов не нахожу), 

воспользуйтес при удалений `implode (php)` , `delete .... where ... in ()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выделяйте уровнями отступа элементы одного уровня. Для вывода html со множеством вставленных значений удобно пользоваться ф-ями printf / [sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php)

По логике сначало нужно стереть записи, если пришли данные на удаление, а потом уже показывать что осталось.

```
<?php
/**
 * Сначала обрабатываем принятые данные для удаления,
 * потом - показываем что осталось.
 */

// обработка удаления данных
if( isset($_POST['delteacher']) && isset( $_POST['delt']) && count( $_POST['delt']>0)) {
    foreach($_POST['delt'] as $key=>$value) {   
        mysql_query(
            sprintf(
                "DELETE FROM `преподаватели` WHERE `фио преподавателя`= '%s'",
                mysql_escape_string( $value)
            );
        printf( "<div><strong>%s</strong> удалён из списка.</div>\n", $value);
    }
}

// Вывод оставшихся записей

// заголовок таблицы
echo <<<EOFHTML
<form action='' method='post'>
    <table class='ram'>
        <tr>
            <td>фио преп</td>
            <td>должность</td>
            <td>степень</td>
            <td>контакт</td>
            <td>
                <input type='submit' name='delteacher' value='Удалить выбранное'>
            </td>
        </tr>
EOFHTML;

// темплейт для строки с данными
$row_tmpl = <<<EOFHTML
<tr>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name='delt[]' value="%s">
    </td>
</tr>
EOFHTML;

// получение данных
$t = "SELECT * FROM `преподаватели`";
$q = mysql_query($t) or die(mysql_error());  
$r = mysql_fetch_array($q);

// построчный вывод полученных данных через вышесозданный темплейт
do {
    printf(
        $row_tmpl,
        $r['фио преподавателя'],
        $r['должность' ],
        $r['степень'],
        $r['контакт преподавателя'],
        $r['фио преподавателя']
    );
} while ( $r = mysql_fetch_array($q) );

// конец таблицы
echo "</table></form>";
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо

а как сделать чтобы при удаление  нескольких значений выводились все те которые удалены а не только последнее?

Comment: пропустил открывающую { в строке 

    foreach($_POST['delt'] as $key=>$value) {

Теперь должно быть ок.

Answer (score 0):

Вот из за таких умников, `php` языком для тапков ... и у тебя жалуется на неожиданный конец, скорее всего что-то не открыл/закрыл ...

```
    <?
echo "<table class='ram'><td>фио преп<td>должность
        <td>степень<td>контакт<td><form action=' ' method='post'>
        <input type='submit' name='delteacher' // ключ по которому удалять будешь препода ...
        value='Удалить выбранное'>";
$t = ("SELECT * FROM `преподаватели`");
$q = mysql_query($t) or die(mysql_error());
$r = mysql_fetch_array($q);

do { 
    echo "<tr><td>" . $r['фио преподавателя'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $r['должность'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $r['степень'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $r['контакт преподавателя'] . "</td>" . "<td>";
    ?> // либо все выводить через эхо либо нет
    <input type='checkbox' name='delt[]' value=" <? $r['фио преподавателя'] ?>">
<?
} while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q));
echo "</table></form>";
if (isset($_POST['delteacher'])) {
    while ($_POST['delt']) {
        foreach ($_POST['delt'] as $key => $value) // нафиг второй цикл?
            echo $value;
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM `преподаватели` WHERE `фио преподавателя`='{$r['фио преподавателя']}'");
        echo $r['фио преподавателя'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: >>нафиг второй цикл?

"Навиг" там был первый, он ничего не делал, а вот второй - вполне рабочий

Comment: А каким образом сделать вывод содержимого если надо в веб форме выбирать для удаления

Comment: Так вы сделайте

    echo '<input...';

Хотя лучше не echo, а

    $outputString = '';
    $outputString .= '...';
    echo $outputString;

while ($_POST['delt']) - это лишнее, удалять к чертам. Вам нужен только foreach ($_POST['delt'] as $value)

И еще - isset($_POST['delteacher']) - вернет TRUE, если был нажат сабмит, но это не значит, что был выбран преподаватель. Надо проверять isset($_POST['delt']). И удалять надо не WHERE $r['фио преподавателя'], а WHERE $value.

Только перед этим необходимо избавиться от возможного SQL-injection.